# The files in the data folder of VScode portable are necessary?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VScode portable and found the files in the data folder are big. It's over 4GB. There are some duplicated ones. eg) github.copilot-1.17.0 and github.copilot-1.18.0. I guess one of them is kind of old/unnecessary one.
So, is it okay to delete them? Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Version: 1.77.3
Commit: 704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
Date: 2023-04-12T09:16:02.548Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
Sandboxed: No

Answer (score 1):

Those are extension installations in the extensions/ folder. You'll need the ones for the extensions you want to use. As for the duplicates, yes, you should be able to safely delete the older (earlier version number) ones. If you want to check what version of an extension is being used at present in VS Code, then open the Extensions View, and hover your mouse over the extension of interest. The version number will be in the hover info.

Possibly related is this issue ticket: [VSC not deleting old extensions #179022](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179022), where the issue reporter is also on Windows with VS Code Portable. One of the maintainers commented there that supposedly if you see a message of the form `<timestamp> [info] Marked extension as uninstalled <extension folder name>` in the logs, that means that version of the extension will be removed when VS Code is restarted. The issue is still being discussed and triaged at the time of this writing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, it means it's a bug. I should follow it.